# Freezing GIF images

Tags: php, javascript, html, gif

I have many animated .gifs on a page. I need a script or code that can freeze the animation of these .gifs so they do not animate and freeze on the first frame.

Currently the backgrounds are table cell backgrounds like this:

```
<td background="animated_background_1.gif">
```

and

```
<td style="background-image:url('animated_background_2.gif');">
```

Comment: I don't think that this can be done in CSS/JS. The best you can do is to extract first frame in PHP (and cache it) and then use it as you are currently using your gif. This way, you'll solve your problem and you'll also make bandwidth consumption smaller, as single frame of gif should be much smaller than whole animated gif file.

Comment: All I can think of is that you create a static `gif` when you upload the animated one and using `javascript` replace the two images on the desired event

Comment: I remember back in the day when animated GIF support was a new feature in browsers you could stop the animations by hitting the stop button when the page was already loaded.  I doubt browsers still do this though, and there's certainly no way in JS/CSS/HTML that I know of to prevent a GIF from animating other than not using animated GIFs in the first place.  Generally, you should avoid animated GIFs except where the animation is actually needed. Otherwise, you're just wasting bandwidth.

Comment: @GordonM, in FF3.5, "stop" button is disabled for loaded pages, but you can hit Esc key to stop gif animations. Though, that is something that end user can do (rather than programmer) and there's tiny chance to stop all animations on the first frame ;)

Comment: Update of previous comment: FF 3.6 has that feature. Don't know about 3.5, as I don't have it installed.

Comment: @binaryLV: Oh, just tried it now, you're right!  Didn't think that would still be in there.  Not that it's any use for the above problem, not using animated GIFs is still the best advice I can offer for that situation :)

Comment: Let them animate. Nothing like a Geocity-retro look :)

Answer (score 1):

The HTML used to display image (or as a background image or whatever):

```
<img src="giftopng.php?image=mypic.gif" alt="" />
```

The test script called:  "giftopng.php"

```
<?php

//Get image name from URL
$image=$_GET['image'];

//Load the image
$img = ImageCreateFromGif($image);

//Convert to PNG and send it to browser
if($img) {
header("Content-Type: image/png");
ImagePNG($img);

//Clean-up memory
ImageDestroy($img);
}
?>
```

You could use something like this (source http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefromgif.php).

If the load is too high then you could cache the static image.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at http://slbkbs.org/jsgif code, it could help you with this issue.

> jsgif is an animated GIF player bookmarklet with support for pausing, going frame-by-frame, playing in reverse, and other features that one might expect from a video player.