# How to freeze animated gifs/convert to jpg with PHP?

Tags: php, gif

I have a page with a bunch of animated gifs and I would like to use PHP to either freeze them on page load or convert each one to jpg/png. I came across this http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefromgif.php but I'm not too familiar with PHP. Any help?

Comment: possible repeat of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5934094/freezing-gif-images (probably not much help though)

Comment: the second example down on this page may help: http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefromgif.php

Comment: I tried that, but I keep getting this error "Resource interpreted as Image but transferred with MIME type text/html"

Comment: can you post the code you have produced?

Comment: Please don't convert GIF to JPG.  You will get compression artifacts.  JPEGs are only for photographs.  You can convert an animated GIF to a non-animated GIF, or to a PNG, without loss of quality.  GIF->JPEG will lose quality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code to convert animated gif to jpg. Taken from **[This comment on the PHP manual entry](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.imagecreatefromgif.php#59853)**

```
<?php

//This function gif2jpeg take three parameter as argument. two argument are optional
//first will take the gif file name. second for file name to save the converted file. third argument is an color array

//EXAMPLE:
$gifName = $_GET['gif_name']; //ABSOLUTE PATH OF THE IMAGE (according to its location)
$c['red']=255;
$c['green']=0;
$c['blue']=0;
echo gif2jpeg($gifName, '', $c);


function gif2jpeg($p_fl, $p_new_fl='', $bgcolor=false){
  list($wd, $ht, $tp, $at)=getimagesize($p_fl);
  $img_src=imagecreatefromgif($p_fl);
  $img_dst=imagecreatetruecolor($wd,$ht);
  $clr['red']=255;
  $clr['green']=255;
  $clr['blue']=255;
  if(is_array($bgcolor)) $clr=$bgcolor;
  $kek=imagecolorallocate($img_dst,
                  $clr['red'],$clr['green'],$clr['blue']);
  imagefill($img_dst,0,0,$kek);
  imagecopyresampled($img_dst, $img_src, 0, 0,
                  0, 0, $wd, $ht, $wd, $ht);
  $draw=true;
  if(strlen($p_new_fl)>0){
    if($hnd=fopen($p_new_fl,'w')){
      $draw=false;
      fclose($hnd);
    }
  }
  if(true==$draw){
    header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
    imagejpeg($img_dst);
  }else imagejpeg($img_dst, $p_new_fl);
  imagedestroy($img_dst);
  imagedestroy($img_src);
}

?>
```

How to use:

- Add the above code into a php file 'convertGifToJpeg.php'
- Add an <img tag. <img src="http://apllicationdomainpath/convertGifToJpeg.php?gif_name=/images/animated_gif.gif"  width="200" height="200"  />
- Make sure have given correct name/path for both the gif image and php file.

Comment: Did you write this function? If not, make sure to attribute the author.